# Java threading issue?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am wondering why the result is not 400 000. There are two threads why does it gets blocked?

```
class IntCell {
    private int n = 0;
    public int getN() {return n;}
    public void setN(int n) {this.n = n;}
}
class Count extends Thread {
    private static IntCell n = new IntCell();
    @Override public void run() {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
            temp = n.getN();
            n.setN(temp + 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Count p = new Count();
        Count q = new Count();
        p.start();
        q.start();
        try { p.join(); q.join(); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        System.out.println("The value of n is " + n.getN());
    }
}
```

Why there is so problem with that?

Comment: What do you mean by "why does it get blocked"? As for what's wrong - imagine if both threads fetch a particular value (say 100), then both increment (to 101), then store the value. Two increments have occurred, but the result is 101 instead of 102...

Comment: You might want to add the results you get. FYI: this is a fundamental thing you need to understand with threading and concurrent updates of values.

Comment: I suggest you go and and read up on how multi-threading works. Your question implies a serious misconception. Multi-threading is so difficult to get right that you need to have a good understanding before you begin.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe it should be 400000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two threads access one object at the same time, they interfere with each other, and the result is not deterministic. For example, imagine that `p` reads the value of `n` and gets, say, 0, then `q` reads the same value and gets 0 too, then `p` sets value to 1 and `q` also sets it to 1 (because it still thinks that it has value 0). Now the value of `n` is increased by 1, even though both counters "incremented" it once. You need to use `synchronized` block to make sure the counters won't interfere with each other. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html for more.

Answer (score 6):

Because the way you increment your variable is not an atomic operation indeed to increment it you:

1. Get the previous value
2. Add one to this value
3. Set a new value

They are 3 operations not done atomically you should either us a `synchronized` block or use an `AtomicInteger` instead.

With a `synchronized` block it would be something like:

```
synchronized (n) {
    temp = n.getN();
    n.setN(temp + 1);
}
```

With an `AtomicInteger` you will need to rewrite your code as next:

```
class IntCell {
    private final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger();
    public int getN() {return n.get();}
    public void incrementN(int n) {this.n.addAndGet(n);}
}

for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    n.incrementN(1);
}
```

The approach with an `AtomicInteger` is non blocking so it will be faster

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you allow for race conditions. Consider the block inside the loop:

```
temp = n.getN();
n.setN(temp + 1);
```

The code context switch between the time you get the current N and by the time you increment it, making you set an "old" value. One way around this is to ensure the inner part of the loop runs in a synchronized block:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    synchronized (n) { / Here!
        temp = n.getN();
        n.setN(temp + 1);
    }
}
```